# Keyboard mainactivity.this

Tags: android

I have three problems I want to learn how to make a customize keyboard and I found this site 
http://www.fampennings.nl/maarten/android/09keyboard/index.htm

but there I have 3 problem about this keyboard.

First problem is that mainactivity isn't work at on key method unlike it was described.

```
             private OnKeyboardActionListener mOnKeyboardActionListener = new   OnKeyboardActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {
        // Get the EditText and its Editable
        View focusCurrent = MainActivity.this.getWindow().getCurrentFocus();

        if( focusCurrent==null || focusCurrent.getClass()!=EditText.class ) return;

        EditText edittext = (EditText) focusCurrent;

        Editable editable = edittext.getText();
```

other problem is that `getSystemServise` give error in Eclipse. I look to a lots of topic but every answers give different idea and I can't apply these ideas.

```
            public void showCustomKeyboard( View v ) {
                   mKeyboardView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mKeyboardView.setEnabled(true);
             if( v!=null ) (      (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
                // getSystemService Gives eRror
```

an other problem is that `registeredittext` method it take `int resid` but there is `findViewById` give error like here.

```
             public void registerEditText(int resid) {
        // Find the EditText 'resid'
        EditText edittext= (EditText)findViewById(resid);      // gives error
        // Make the custom keyboard appear
        edittext.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
```

Comment: There are many Android developer support sites on the Internet, offering help in many languages. You may have better luck using a site that is in a language that is more comfortable for you. I list several such sites at http://www.andglobe.com.

Comment: there are not my country and our country arent interesting in make a andorid application or other programming :)